# Smarty is not displaying the template

Tags: php, jquery, html, smarty

I am trying to build a menu for my website and using Smarty to display the pages. When user click on the Logout option the JQuery send an Ajax call to index.php script which contain the code for Smarty to display the page but it is not displaying it. It was working fine before I added the menu. There is no error in the firebug too. Can someone put me in the right direction.

Here is PHP code

```
    if (isset($_POST['menu_index']))
    {
        if ($_POST['menu_index'] == 'Logout')
        {
            $smarty->display("login.tpl");  
            exit;            
        }
    }
```

Here is JQuery code

```
        $('ul li a').on('click', function() {
            var menuItemIndex = $(this).data('val');
            console.log(menuItemIndex);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data: {
                'menu_index': menuItemIndex
                }, 
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function(errorMsg) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
                });
            });
```

Here is HTML Code

```
<form name="mainmenu" id="mainmenu">
    <div id='content'>
       <div id='jqxMenu'>
            <ul>
                <li>Maintanence
                    <ul style='width: 180px;'>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addCategory">Add Category</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addSubCategory">Add Sub-category</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Process Order
                    <ul style='width: 180px;'>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addShipOrder">Ship Order</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addChangeOrder">Change Order Status</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Reports
                    <ul style='width: 180x;'>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addOrderStation">Orders by station</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addOrderDate">Orders by date</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-val="addPendingOrder">Pending Orders</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-val="Logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the `dataType` of AJAX request is `json`. It will never display a page unless you replace your `alert` in `success` with redirection code to your login page.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ejay. I am new to this kind of programming. How can I send a success response from PHP and redirect it in JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you don't understand how **Smarty** works, but I can tell you that you don't have any template in html code which is **very important** for this kind of programming.

You need to make template for menu and call it menu.tpl -> then include it on index.tpl ...

For more informations take a look www.smarty.net